# part number (1, 2, 3) as word (one, deux, trois)?

Tags: numbering, babel, fmtcount

Can someone please explain to me, why I get:

### Part ONE

but then:

### Part DEUX

### Part TROIS

---

In addition to an explanation, any successful solution to this rather odd phenomenon would be highly appreciated.

---

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{fmtcount}       %For ''Part One'' instead of ''Part 1''
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \renewcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\numberstring{part}}
\begin{document}
    \part{This is Just a Part}
    \part{This is Yet another Part}
    \part{And, in Fact, One More}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks very similar to a bug of `fmtcount` [I reported here](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&category=fmtcount&status=All&search_string=&key=35)

Comment: It may be due to conflicting options to `babel`...

Comment: Just for information. With commented `\usepackage{fontspec}` it works when compiled with PDFLaTeX. (Edit: XeLaTeX with fontspec also. Can't test Lua here)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi no it doesn't. At least not with an up to date TL 2013

Comment: @cgnieder OK, I am having babel 3.8 (instead of 3.9) and fmtcount 1.31 (instead of 2.02) here. Sorry

Comment: BTW: this is unrelated to sectioning, `titlesec` or parts: it can be reproduced with any counter as long as `babel` is loaded with at least two languages, the last one being `british`. It triggers a warning in the log: `Package fmtcount Warning: No support for \numberstring for language 'british'`

Comment: This is indeed due to the same bug that @cgnieder reported. This has now been fixed in v2.03, which I've just uploaded to CTAN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in `fmtcount` that doesn't load `fc-british.def`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[french,british]{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}       %For ''Part One'' instead of ''Part 1''
\makeatletter
\input{fc-british.def}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \renewcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\numberstring{part}}
\begin{document}
    \part{This is Just a Part}
    \part{This is Yet another Part}
    \part{And, in Fact, One More}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\FCloadlang{british}` rather than `\makeatletter\input{fc-british.def}\makeatother`. (Although now the bug has been fixed it should now load it automatically.)